# Есть ли какая либо функция на проверку выхода из массива?

Tags: java, массивы, строки

Есть код, в котором нужно сделать циклический сдвиг символов (Ввод 1: qwerty; Ввод 2: 2; Вывод => tyqwer)

Написал код, как мне кажется, он должен работать верно, но столкнулся с проблемой того, что массив выходит за свои границы, что логично. Возникает вопрос, есть ли какая-либо функция, которая позволяет выходить за границу массива для проверки?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Write string");
        String str = sc.next();
        System.out.println("Write number");
        int num = sc.nextInt();
        char[] symbols = str.toCharArray();
        // boolean first = true;
        int k = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < symbols.length; i++) {
            if((symbols[i+num]) > symbols.length-1){
                symbols[k] = symbols[i];
                System.out.print(symbols[k]);
                k++;
            }else{
                symbols[i+num] = symbols[i];
                System.out.print(symbols[i+num]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Конкретная задача вполне решается без массивов:

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Write string");
    String str = sc.next();
    System.out.println("Write number");
    int num = sc.nextInt();

    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        char last = str.charAt(str.length()-1);
        str = last + str.substring(0, str.length()-1);
    }
    System.out.println(str);
```

Использовать StringBuilder конечно будет более корректно, но чтоб не усложнять можно и так. Выход за пределы массива можно проверить через сравнение аргумента с размером массива или даже через исключение. Для циклических перестановок в промышленных масштабах хорошо подойдет LinkedList. У листов нет ограничений на размер.